# How to use complex variables in a Gurobi problem

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, complex-numbers, gurobi

I currently solve optimization problems with complex variables using CVX + Mosek, on MATLAB. I'm now considering switching to Gurobi + Python for some applications.

1. Is there a way to declare complex values (both inside constraints and as optimization variables) directly into Gurobi's Python interface?
2. If not, which are good modeling languages, with Python interface, that automates the reduction of the problem to real variables before calling the solver?

I know, for instance, that [YALMIP does this reduction](https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/complexproblems/) (though no Python interface), and [newer versions of CVXPY also](https://www.cvxpy.org/updates/index.html) (but I haven't used it extensively, and don't know if it already has good performance, is stable, and reasonably complete). Any thoughts on these issues and recommendations of other interfaces are thus welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only [possible variables](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/variables.html) in Gurobi are:

- Integer;
- Binary;
- Continuous;
- Semi-Continuous and;
- Semi-Integer.

Also, I don't know the problem you're trying to solve, but complex number are quite strange for linear optimization.

[The complex plane isn't a ordered field](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Numbers_cannot_be_Totally_Ordered), so that is not possible to say that a given complex number z1 > z2

You'll probably have to model your problem in such way that you can decompose the constraints with real and imaginary parts, so that you can work only with real numbers.

Comment: I think the poster meant that some decision variables (and data) are complex, not that the objective function is complex. Sometimes it can be easily mapped manually into R^2, but in other cases it can become messy. CVXPY (and YALMIP) is one of the few modeling tools that I know of that support complex numbers. CVXPY of course will insist on a real valued objective.

Comment: That's indeed what I meant. Your answers solve my issue. Complementing it for anyone's future reference, CVXPY has a Reductions API, and inside it, a Complex2Real class with methods to lift complex variables. Those are automatically called when declaring a problem with complex variables, and cast the problem to en equivalent but purely real one, before calling the solver. I'll stick to it for now.